# Using Render With Repeat in Plain Text Email

Tags: visualforce, email-template, rendered

I have a VF page set up as an email template.  I have a repeat tag on the HTML part of my template that pulls in Cases based upon some criteria contained in an OutputPanel.  I am trying to accomplish the same thing on the Plain Text version of my template, but when I try to put in an outputPanel I get an error:

```
messaging:plainTextEmailBody> cannot contain <apex:outputPanel
```

Does anyone know how I can get a render attribute inside my Repeat attribute for the plain text email body?

Answer (score 1):

Since `messaging:plainTextEmailBody` can't have HTML, and, an `outputPanel` is a `div` or `span` and hence it won't work. So, how to work around?

**Option 1: Use a custom component w/ controller**

So, assuming you are getting Cases for an Account:

Create a custom component `<c:theCases accountId={!someAcctMergeField}/>`

The custom component would:

1. Be associated with a controller
2. Do the filtering in the controller based on values passed through the component's attributes and/or queried from the database
3. Return a list of Cases ...
4. That are the `value={!...}` attribute of the `repeat` and ...
5. Can be rendered as HTML in the `HtmlEmailBody` and as plain text in the `plainTextEmailBody`

That is, move the rendering logic out to the custom component's controller

> Update: You could also use the `rendered=` attribute on the `<c:myCustomComponent ..>` to decide to render the component at all (in effect, acting like the outputPanel rendered= )

**Option 2 - move the rendering condition onto the `apex:repeat`** (if possible)