# Can I use <messaging:htmlEmailBody> and <messaging:plainTextEmailBody> in the same template?

Tags: visualforce, email-template, vf-email-template

I wonder if it is possible to use `<messaging:htmlEmailBody>` and `<messaging:plainTextEmailBody>` in the same template? Nothing is mentioned about it in the official [Visualforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_messaging_emailTemplate.htm).

> The messaging:plainTextEmailBody must be a child of messaging:emailTemplate

If it is not possible, then how can I create a text version of this email?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://www.emizentech.com/blog/visualforce-email-templates-in-salesforce.html
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122198/using-render-with-repeat-in-plain-text-email
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12899/using-a-component-to-add-attachments-to-visualforce-email-template-and-showing-e

Comment: works for me, using version 58.0

Comment: Apparently, moving <messaging:plainTextEmailBody> above <messaging:htmlEmailBody> fixed the issue.